# override width from _Layout.cshtml

Tags: c#, css, .net, model-view-controller, shared

In my shared layout I have a width specified on my body-container div.

Is there a way to override this width in just one of my views? 
 i want to keep using the remaining parts of the shared layout.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are 3 solutions:

1) put body-containers in every view.

2) Inside view `<style> .body-container {width: 1000px!important} </style>`

3) use javascript to override css.

Answer (score 0):

You could specify the width using a parameter that is passed in the ViewBag. If the parameter does not exist, use the default value.

In _Layout.cshtml:

```
@{ var layoutWidth = ViewBag.LayoutWidth ?? "640px" /* default value */;  }
<div id="body-container" style="width: @layoutWidth;"> ... </div>
```

In the View that overrides the width:

```
@{ ViewBag.LayoutWidth = "480px"; }
```